# How to change the highlight color of multiple (at least two) different span or div concurrently by hover or mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on text content that sometimes has different parts being related to each other, and I'd like to let user hover/mouseover any of the related parts, and accordingly highlight all the related parts at the same time with the same highlight color.

What's the quickest way to do this, assuming that I do have all the information (on the server) regarding which parts are related, prior to generating the content into HTML. I.e. I can put in the proper css or javascript to get the needed setup in ad hoc, per page basis.

Comment: Well, the quickest way to get an answer would be to add some useful details to your question, for example *how do you know what parts relate to other parts*?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be toggling a class on your body or a top container element and defining the CSS in such a way that it descendants are corrected colored/highlighted etc. This will be faster than adding/removing classes from each element in the association.

For example: if all related elements have the class "rel-1" then you can have a CSS definition like:

```
body.rel-1 .rel-1 {
    background-color: #ddd;
    /* .. other styles */
}
```

And on hover over any element with class `rel-1`, toggle the same class in the body/container element.

For example:

```
$('.rel-1').mouseover(function() {
    $(body).addClass('rel-1');
});

$('.rel-1').mouseout(function() {
    $(body).removeClass();
});
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this can be done using jquery pretty easily.

First, I'd set up html elements with attributes. I'm using `thisisfor`, you can use ([almost](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html)) anything. So if you can predetermine which 'group' each item belongs to on the server side, you can classify them with an attribute of your choice, and then whatever 'group'.

**html**

```
<div class="hoverme" thisisfor="group3">What group are we in?</div>
<div class="hoverme" thisisfor="group3">What group are we in?</div>
<div class="hoverme" thisisfor="group2">What group are we in?</div>
<div class="hoverme" thisisfor="group4">What group are we in?</div>
```

Then, using jquery, you can set up a hover event that checks an attribute, the `thisisfor` attribute in our case:

**jquery**

```
$("[thisisfor]").hover(function(){ /* anything with 'thisisfor' attribute */

    var group = $(this).attr('thisisfor');  /* store its value as variable 'group' */

    $("[thisisfor="+ group +"]").html(group);  /* all with this group that was hovered....change the text (or whatever your plan is) */

});​
```

**[See my example](http://jsfiddle.net/F66F7/2/)**

But, yea, the possibilities are endless using attributes...